# Resolving relations inside a chain transaction

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I've tested the possibility of resolving the relations with the "composer-client" library. I see in the API reference that the "composer-client.AssetRegistry"  class has "resolve" and "resolveAll" Methods from its super-class "Registry". The methods are useful when developing a client application.

However, the composer-**runtime**.AssetRegistry has only "get" and "getAll" methods, which return registry records **without** resolving the "relations".

I can't seem to find any way of resolving the relations inside the transaction code. Any clues on that? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the composer-runtime doesn't offer the resolve/resolveAll methods currently. Having said that, you may not need these functions since any objects that are passed as parameters to the transaction code should be fully resolved and so you should be able to access everything you need from the objects that you're passed.

I guess it depends on what your use case is really.  If you're wanting to get assets from AssetRegistries independently from within your transaction code then you'll have to resolve the relationships manually, following the relationships using the runtime API as things currently stand.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is the approach we're using right now. I hope that this functionality is planned in for the next release.